# Send method to subprocess

Tags: python, dynamic, multiprocessing, twisted

I'm implementing a process pool using Twisted. The ultimate goal is a simple deferToProcess function, much like deferToThread. I'm aware of the ampoule module, but I'm avoiding it because it's apparently not very maintained, because it requires amp subclasses, and because I'm interested in writing this anyway.

I want to be able to call any arbitrary static function in the current project from deferToProcess. Twisted creates any arbitrary process, so I got it to invoke the current Python interpreter, with a duplicated import path. To find a module level function you could simply determine which module the function resides in, then import the module and call the function. It occurred to me it might be tricky to pass a function reference to say, a static class method or a lambda.

To figure out what my options were, I took a look at Python's multiprocessing module. Everything I tried worked perfectly, even a reference to a global object in the parent process.

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def test():
...             print 'Found it!'
...
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Test.test, args=())
>>> p.start()
Found it!
>>> import sys
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: sys.stdout.write('hello\r\n'), args=())
>>> p.start()
hello
>>> hm='Testing'
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: sys.stdout.write(hm), args=())
>>> p.start()
Testing
```

Obviously Python must fork the child processes with all of that data intact. Since Twisted actually spawns fresh processes, is there a reasonable way to try to recover the full path to call a method, assuming one exists (e.g. method is not dynamic)? That includes static module level functions, lambda functions assigned to a module level variable, and static methods of classes. I don't see a way to do this

For instance, running the hypothetical function

```
findCallPath(Test.test)
```

might return

```
module.module.module.Test.test
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems I could serialize the functions with Dill (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill), but I'm still curious about my original question as well.

Comment: Please don't use the title of your question to "tag" it. I have edited the title. The tagging system is the best way to make sure people interested in your topic see your question.

Comment: "I'm aware of the ampoule module, but I'm avoiding it because it's apparently not very maintained" - not a good reason not to maintain something.  This is how open source works - ownership of a project often changes hands.

Comment: What I mean to say is that (according to Google) there are issues with the ampoule module that are not fixed and are not likely to be fixed in the near future because the module isn't maintained by anyone anymore. I could fix the issues myself, but I'm unfamiliar with the internal code and I don't like their interface due to it's reliance on amp subclasses anyway. Thus it's more productive for me to write a similar alternative than to try to use ampoule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you want is `twisted.python.reflect.fullyQualifiedName`, which *almost* does what you want:

```
>>> from twisted.python.reflect import fullyQualifiedName
>>> fullyQualifiedName(fullyQualifiedName)
'twisted.python.reflect.fullyQualifiedName'
```

However, it does fall short when interacting with static methods:

```
>>> class Something(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def somethingElse():
...         pass
... 
>>> fullyQualifiedName(Something.somethingElse)
'__main__.somethingElse'
```

Although this is arguably a bug - we'd probably accept a patch that would fix it :).

The reverse operation is `twisted.python.reflect.namedAny` (so called because there are other functions like `namedClass` and `namedModule`, but this will return any type of thing):

```
>>> from twisted.python.reflect import namedAny
>>> namedAny(fullyQualifiedName(namedAny)) is namedAny
True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `twisted.python.reflect.fullyQualifiedName`